# SQL server -Loop through table and insert if not present, update if present

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am coming from Oracle background where I have used cursors for row updates.

Needed the easiest way to write looping logic. Here is the scenario

I have `table1_intermediate` which has `Id`,`eligVal` along with others
and `table2_intermediate`has `Id`,`inEligVal` along with others

I have a main table `table_main` which has 3 columns `Id`,`eligVal`,`inEligVal` along with others

I want to insert records from both `table1_intermediate` and `table2_intermediate` into main table.
But if Id is already present( due to insert from one table), I want to update the same record coming from the 2nd intermediate table.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `merge` could do the job https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using two stored procedures. One to insert the value from table1 like ?:

```
 Begin 
 If Not Exists (Select * from table_main where Id=@Id) 
     Begin 
     Insert into table_main(Id,eligVal) values(@Id,@eligVal)
     End
 End
```

and then insert a new row if Id is new or else update the same like :

```
Begin
If Not Exists (Select * from table_main where Id=@Id)
    Begin
    Insert into table_main(Id,inEligVal) values(@Id,@inEligVal)
    End
Else
    Begin
    Update table_main Set inEligVal=@inEligVal where Id=@Id
    End
End
```

Comment: There's a capability which called - merge specifically for cases like this. Why would you go and implement this yourself?

Comment: In either case, for each record loop, you suggest creating a temp table inside SP?